# A multi-conditional switch statement?

Tags: php, switch-statement

This is something that I haven't seen in the PHPdoc for `switch()` so I'm not sure if it's possible, but I'd like to have a case which is multi-conditional, such as:

```
switch($this) {
   case "yes" || "maybe":
      include "filename.php";
      break;
   ... 
}
```

Is this valid syntax/is this even possible with a `switch()` statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually you'd just use case fall-through.

```
switch($this) {
   case "yes":
   case "maybe":
      include "filename.php";
      break;
   ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this valid syntax/is this even possible with a switch() statement?

No and no. The expression will be evaluated as `("yes" or "maybe")`, which will result in `true`. `switch` will then test against that result.

You want to use

```
case "yes":
case "maybe":
// some code
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
switch($this) { 
   case "yes":
   case "maybe": 
      include "filename.php"; 
      break; 
   ...  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with fall-through:

```
switch ($this) {
    case "yes":
    case "no":
        include "filename.php";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just specify two cases without breaking the first one, like so:

```
switch($this) {
   case "yes":
   case "maybe":
      include "filename.php";
      break;
   ... 
}
```

If you don't break a case, then any code for that case is run and continues on to execute additional code until the execution is broken. It will continue through *all* cases below it until it sees a `break`.